# How to add task in Azure DevOps release pipeline using rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to add task in Azure DevOps release pipeline using rest API -

Here is rest API for updating release pipeline  -

PUT [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0)

for example if I want to add powershell task in my existing release pipeline in Dev stage, What request body I need to put ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing(clicking F12 to capture corresponding browser network requests), this request body for this API: [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is the same content when you call this API: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get its definition.

Therefore, you could get the release pipeline definition firstly, and then add below PowerShell task code segment to `workflowTasks array`, which locates in the result's `environments array` >>`dev stage`>>`deployPhases array`>>`workflowTasks array`

```
{
  "environment": {},
  "taskId": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
  "version": "2.*",
  "name": "PowerShell Script test",
  "refName": "",
  "enabled": true,
  "alwaysRun": false,
  "continueOnError": false,
  "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
  "definitionType": "task",
  "overrideInputs": {},
  "condition": "succeeded()",
  "inputs": {
    "targetType": "inline",
    "filePath": "",
    "arguments": "",
    "script": "# Write your PowerShell commands here.\n\nWrite-Host \"Hello World\"\n",
    "errorActionPreference": "stop",
    "failOnStderr": "false",
    "showWarnings": "false",
    "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
    "pwsh": "false",
    "workingDirectory": ""
  }
}
```

And then there will an extra PowerShell task in Dev stage.
[image]
BTW, each updates will generate a new `revision`, which is the latest version of release definition, and you need to use the latest version to update release pipeline the next time.